# JavaScript - Problem getting data from promise object

Tags: javascript

So, I'm new to using promise object... I'm trying to make a Facebook instant game which uses the function `FBInstant.player.getDataAsync().then()`. This function returns a promise and I have no clue how to use the data returned other than with `console.log()`. If I try to insert the data to a defined variable it becomes unidentified.

Example:

```
User = [];
FBInstant.player.getDataAsync(['name']).then(function(data) {
    User['name'] = data['name'];
});

console.log(User['name']) // return unidentified.
```

Sorry for my poor explanation I'm new to this and I'm just trying to accomplish a simple task.

Comment: because `console.log(User['name'])` is read BEFORE `User['name'] = data['name'];` runs. That is how Asynchronous calls work. You need to do the logic inside of that then() or call the next step.

Answer (score 0):

```
User = [];
FBInstant.player.getDataAsync(['name']).then(function(data) {
    User['name'] = data['name'];
    console.log(User['name'])
});
```

This should give you a response